# Replacing line break in linux tail -f command

Tags: javascript, linux, shell, terminal

Is there any way to use *tail -f* command in Linux and replacing line breaks with HTML linebreak tag br>. I am sending tail -f output to a web page through WebSocket but my javascript is not treating /n as a line break. Also, replacing in javascript layer is very costly, I want to achieve it in Linux node itself. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use sed command to create a html style file with <br>

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe tail into another function to do the replacement you want. For example, to use `sed` to add a `<br>` at the end of each line, you could use:

```
tail -f <whatever> | sed 's/$/<br>/'
```

Comment: It will work, however quite ineffective in this form. tail -f constantly produces something. Maybe one should run sed on whatever file once every one, five, ten minutes?

Comment: Why is it ineffective? `sed` is specifically intended to operate on streams, that's why it's called the "Stream Editor"

Comment: Actually I am going to comment on this only if any feedback comes in from the question author. I need to double check something. It's just my first thought that running sed on tail is OK, but on tail -f I don't like. Just a first impression.